# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Could not parse as expression with an url

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm putting a button on page 1 to navigate to page 2. Page 1 and 2 are on different controllers.

This is the code of my button. The pid is the ID of the project. p.id gives the ID of the project. But I don't know what the problem here is.

```
<td><a th:href="@{/projects/project/{pid}/clusters(pid=${p.id})" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Clusters</a></td>
```

The exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "@{/projects/project/{pid}/clusters(pid=${p.id})" (projects:53)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed one curly bracket at the end of expression

```
<a th:href="@{/projects/project/{pid}/clusters(pid=${p.id})}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Clusters</a>
```